# Why there are two different tests in my Test Navigator in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, xctest

Why there are two different tests as it is on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mean the difference between the blue T and the violet rT?

When you create a test target using File->New->Target->iOS or OS X->Test->...Test Bundle
you get a dialog where you sau "Target to be tested".
When you choose such a target, you get the blue Ts for classes in your test target.

Sometimes you can't choose a target (or you don't want to). For example it is impossible at the moment to choose your Watch OS (extension) as a test target. In this case, you can only test some classes, not the target as a whole. 
In this case your test classes get a violet rT.